# Issue integrating SQLITE3 date query into MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, date

I have this simple query which is mean't to fetch all the order dates from my table

```
select (orderDate, "%m-%Y")) from customerorders
```

However, it does not work.

I have also tried to swap the date and month formats around:

```
select (orderDate, "%%Y-%m")) from customerorders
```

The structure of the order dates in my table are in the DATE FORMAT:

```
'2019-01-01'
```

3rd query

```
select COUNT(orderid) as OrderCount,
DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, "%m-%Y")) as month
FROM customerOrders
WHERE milkOptions = 'Coconut'
group by month
order by DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, "%Y")
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite?

Comment: Your parentheses don't balance.  And this code wouldn't work in any database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this, via `DATE_FORMAT` function:

```
select DATE_FORMAT('2019-01-01', "%m-%Y")
```

or for you this will be:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, "%m-%Y") from customerorders
```

Or different order:

```
select DATE_FORMAT('2019-01-01', "%y-%M")
```

or for you this will be:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, "%y-%M") from customerorders
```

[Here is a small DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=45e0c590e8de4a496b399b74546827a0)

And here you can find more info about the function(and other ones):
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

**UPDATE**

```
select COUNT(orderid) as OrderCount,
DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, "%m-%Y") as month
FROM customerOrders
WHERE milkOptions = 'Coconut'
group by month
order by DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, "%Y");
```

or:

```
select COUNT(orderid) as OrderCount
      , DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, "%m-%Y") as month
FROM customerOrders
WHERE milkOptions = 'Coconut'
group by month
order by month;
```

Comment: Hi @grimReaperZ your feedback on this answer would be nice. Cheers!

Comment: Hi. I will mark as correct if you could just integrate your answer with my 3rd query in the updated question. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, @grimReaperZ, I did it. Check it out. Also, you can vote up and mark as correct. Thanks!